# Sharepoint - (list) Conditional Formatting after filter

Tags: list, sharepoint, formatting, conditional-statements

I have been use this code in scripts editor to formatting the lines of my list in sharepoint online application.

This script work fine! but is run only when the page is loaded, if is necessary make filters in the list the formatting is lost.....

some ideia to fix? or other way to do conditional formatting in sharepoint?

```html
<script src="https://....jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $Text = $("td .ms-vb2:contains('PENDENTE DE EVIDENCIA')").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == "PENDENTE DE EVIDENCIA";})
        $Text.parent().css("background-color", "#CECECE");
        
        $Text = $("td .ms-vb2:contains('ATENDIDO')");
        $Text.parent().css("background-color", "#FFFF66");

ctx.skipNextAnimation = true

    }); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Client Site Rendering (CSR):

This will handle any changes made to the list (sorting/filtering/etc) and update your views according to your rules.

[Here's how it works](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
    var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
    for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
      // UPDATE THE LOGIC HERE FOR WHAT MAKES SENSE FOR YOU
      var isApproved = rows[i]["_ModerationStatus"] == "Approved";
      if (isApproved)
      {
        var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
        var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
        tr.style.backgroundColor = "#ada";
      }
    }
  }
});
```